# Python multiple classes inheritance error. How can I initialize them correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to build a python3 module for an HTTP RESTful API that I've coded.

My idea was to create a `base` class that should have a `request.Session()` attribute so I can assign an authorization token header to that and don't worry about it anymore and also a logger function and so on.
The problem is that a class called `User` inherits from 2 classes: `PublicUser` and `base` and I can't initialize them correctly.

It's the first time that I'm working with inherited class so obviously I'm missing something.

This is my folder structure:

```
examplemodule/
  |--> __init__.py
  |--> classes/
        |-->  base.py
        |-->  user.py
```

`base.py`

```
from requests import Session
from requests.sessions import session


class Logger:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def log(self, message):
        print(message)


class Base:
    def __init__(self, token=None):
        if not hasattr(self, 'logger'):
            self.logger = Logger()
        if not hasattr(self, 'session'):
            self.session = Session()
            self.session.headers.update(
                {'authorization': 'Token {}'.format(token)}
            )
            # Try to login to see if token is valid, if not raise exception
            # If token is valid then the retrieved user json is saved
            self._user = {
                'id': 1,
                'username': 'test1',
                'email': 'test@test.com'
            }
```

`user.py`

```
from .base import Base

PUBBLIC_USER_ATTRS = ['id', 'username']
PRIVATE_USER_ATTRS = ['email']


class PublicUser:
    def __init__(self, user):
        for k in PUBBLIC_USER_ATTRS:
            setattr(self, k, user[k])


class User(Base, PublicUser):
    def __init__(self, token=None):
        super(Base, self).__init__(token=token)
        super(PublicUser, self).__init__(self._user)
        for k in PRIVATE_USER_ATTRS:
            setattr(self, k, self._user[k])
```

`__init__.py`

```
from .classes.user import User
```

then to test my module I run:

```
import examplemodule
examplemodule.User(token='')
```

but unfortunately I get a `TypeError` at `super(Base, self).__init__(token=token)`

> TypeError: super() takes no keyword arguments

What is the best way to get through this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`super` is meant for *cooperative* inheritance, where all involved classes are using `super` in a way that ensures all necessary methods are called. That means `super` should *also* be used by base classes, even if all they inherit from is `object`.

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, *, token=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if not hasattr(self, 'logger'):
            self.logger = Logger()
        if not hasattr(self, 'session'):
            self.session = Session()
            self.session.headers.update(
                {'authorization': 'Token {}'.format(token)}
            )
            # Try to login to see if token is valid, if not raise exception
            # If token is valid then the retrieved user json is saved
            self._user = {
                'id': 1,
                'username': 'test1',
                'email': 'test@test.com'
            }

class PublicUser:
    def __init__(self, *, id, username, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.id = id
        self.username = username
        
class User(Base, PublicUser):
    def __init__(self, *, email, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.email = email


u = User(token='...', id='...', username='...', email='...')
```

`User.__init__` only has to make one call to `super().__init__`, knowing that its base classes also use `super().__init__` to always call the next `__init__`, until reaching the end of the MRO. You start with `User.__init__`, which calls `Base.__init__`, which calls `PublicUser.__init__` (*not* `object.__init__`), which finally calls `object.__init__`.

At each step, the remaining keyword arguments are split between the "known" arguments, which are handled, and the "unknown" arguments, which are passed up the line. Eventually, all keyword objects should be extracted and handled by the time `object.__init__` is called.

See https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for a more thorough explanation of how this works in practiced (in particular, why keyword arguments are preferred over positional arguments).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to call constructors of super-classes like this:

```
Base.__init__(self, token=token)
PublicUser.__init__(self, self._user)
```

Comment: What are the differences between this approach and @chepner 's one?

Comment: it is just my opinion but I consider this more explicit and readable. That is only difference I see. You can use normal arguments which is more self documenting then just `**kwargs`